# Cannot turn the screen off while video is playing

Tags: android, screen, android-videoview

I have a VideoView in my activity, which I use only as a background, with a video on looping mode.

The screen does not go into sleep mode automatically. I tried manually counting the seconds since the last user interactivity, but I was still not able to force the screen to turn off.

I have tried PowerManager, acquiring locks and goToSleep() function,  but I still haven't managed to turn my screen off.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an ancient question, but I thought I'd write an answer anyway since this page shows up in Google searches.

I solved the same problem using this code:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, so it's the VideoView that causes screen not off issue. `VideoView` -> `com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout()` -> `com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.handleNotObscuredLocked()` -> add `KEEP_SCREEN_ON` flag to the window which contains VideoView -> system_server acquire a `WakeLock` of type `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDPM.lockNow();
```

That will lock your phone (same as pressing the power/lock button) and thus turn of the screen.

Comment: I get "java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid 10087 for policy #3". Do I have to set some admin privileges beforehand?

Comment: Read about solving this issue here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem using this code:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
}
```

});

Comment: mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. The following code has solved my problem. Hope it can help you.

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(false);
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solved** Add one line of code after setContentView() in onCreate()

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flag);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

**In Fragment**

```
        getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```